# SSIS package failure on catalog tools : send file to SFTP

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a SSIS package that send file to SFTP.
When I run the package on visual studio it works sucessful.
I did deploy this package to dev environment but when I run the package via Integration Services Cataloge on tools I got the following error:

Send to SFTP:Error: Could not load file or assembly 'WinSCPnet, Version=1.6.4.9590, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2271ec4a3c56d0bf' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Is there anyone here that know how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have WinSCP (or WinSCPnet.dll) installed on your SSIS server?

Comment: yes I have this installed

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy file WinSCPnet.dll into your gac. [www.winscpnet.com has good instructions for download](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install) and instructions specific for [using it with SSIS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis).